# Unit testing ordered SQL queries

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, h2

I am writing unit tests on queries where the results must be returned in a specific sorted order. We are using the Java H2 in memory database.

I want to make sure that the "order by" statements are being executed correctly. I'm not trying test H2, I accept it's correct, I'm trying to test that I have issued correct the SQL statement to return the correctly sorted results.

I'm thinking something like a way to tell H2 to randomise the results each time before sorting or perhaps some kind of SQL insertion that inserts rows in a random order to the tables each time. Hopefully this tests the ordering is correct. I know it's no guarantee because the database determines it's own internal order but thought I'd throw it in as an idea I was thinking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you shouldn't randomize the H2 results. I would suggest you to write two or three tests with same queries and different `order by`. In this case you ensure that different order parameters leads to results in correct sorted order.

Comment: Can you give us some example? It's not exactly clear what you mean.

Answer (score -1):

you need to insert only two rows that must not change (don't insert random data). For example, if you have a User entity with the following columns: id, name, surname.

You insert 2 rows:

```
#id# name # surname #
#####################
#1# john  # doe     #
#2# eva   # nondoe  #
```

And for example, if you are interested in the name column then you write a test like this.

```
//BUILD
insertData();

//OPERATE
List<User> result = selectAllDataByNameAsc();

//CHECK
assertThat(result.get(0).getName()).isEqualTo("eva");
```

This is enough. Two rows are enough to test your sorting query.

Comment: Did you consider [this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/queries-order.html)? "If sorting is not chosen, the rows will be returned in an unspecified order. The actual order in that case will depend on the scan and join plan types and the order on disk, but it must not be relied on. A particular output ordering can only be guaranteed if the sort step is explicitly chosen." Theoretically your test might give false positives when no ORDER BY is specified.

Comment: Yes, I did. SelectAllDataByNameAsc implies order by Name ASC. I did not write the SQL but from the name of the method, it could be implied order by name ASC is used.

Comment: Okay, let me put it this way. The documentation says, that `SELECT * FROM users` is not guaranteed to return "john" first. Which means if `selectAllDataByNameAsc()` under the hood does this query without `ORDER BY name` the test can produce a false positive. That is, it can pass when it should fail.